# Unable to access $refs in component method

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to access a ref that is defined within a template, when an element is clicked. Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.2.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <site-nav></site-nav>
        </div>
        <script src="js/vjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my Vue code

```
var siteNav = Vue.component("site-nav", {
    template: `<div v-on:click="testMethod">Click me</div>
    <div ref="testref"></div>`,
    methods: {
        testMethod: function(event) {
            console.log(self.$refs);
        },
    },
});


var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
});
```

When clicking the "Click me" element, the console logs show that the `$refs` of the component element are inaccessible. I think this might be occurring because of a scope issue, or because the methods aren't seeing the refs before they get rendered.

What's going on here? I know I'm missing something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue 2 you should wrap your component template by one root element (html or Vue component) like :

```
var siteNav = Vue.component("site-nav", {
    template: `<div><div v-on:click="testMethod">Click me</div>
    <div ref="testref"></div></div>`,
   
});
```

then access the `$refs` using `this` which refers to component instance :

```
console.log(this.$refs);
```

```js
var siteNav = Vue.component("site-nav", {
    template: `<div><div v-on:click="testMethod">Click me</div>
    <div ref="testref">test</div></div>`,
    methods: {
        testMethod: function(event) {
            console.log(this.$refs.testref);
        },
    },
});


var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.2.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <site-nav></site-nav>
        </div>
        <script src="js/vjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```